# How to drop rows with empty string values in certain columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df.dropna(subset=[column_name], inplace=True)
```

I have a dataframe with some missing values in some column (column_name). For example, one value is the empty string, ''. But the code above doesn't drop the row with such empty values.

Isn't the code right way  to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not drop those because they are not `na` they are an empty string. For those you would have to do something like:

```
rows_to_drop = df[df[column_name]==''].index
df.drop(rows_to_drop, inplace=True)
```

Alternative:

Something like this would also work:

```
df = df.loc[df[column_name]!='',:]
```